# unexpected tIDENTIFIER with expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving the following error related to the `announcement.rb`:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
>   (SyntaxError) puts "fatal error: " + e.message

I have reviewed the below code and it appears to be correct. Does someone seem the error?

```
Twit::Part.new :announcement do
  every 30, :minutes do
    ids = @config[:ids].shift(15)  # take 25 ids at a time
    next if ids.empty?  # do not do anything if there are no ids anymore

    ids.each do |id|
      begin
        # look up the user name behind the ID, keep in mind that the
        # endpoint for that might be rate limited
        username = bot.user(id, skip_status: true)&.screen_name
        if username.nil?
          @config[:ids] << id
          next
        end

        # finally, tweet the message:
        bot.tweet "@#{username} Hey, check out my cool site!”
        # and add the id to the :already_tweeted list
        @config[:already_tweeted] << id
      rescue => e
        puts "fatal error: " + e.message
        @config[:ids] << id
      end
    end
    bot.save_config
  end
end
```

Comment: Even the crappy Ruby parser from [so]'s syntax highlighter has found the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"@#{username} Hey, check out my cool site!”
                                          ↑
```

should be

```
"@#{username} Hey, check out my cool site!"
                                          ↑
```

Comment: Great eyes! Thanks

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/how-to-disable-smart-quotes